# SQL column name with a pound sign

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and recently I've had problems working with my table that contains a column name of 'S#'. 
So what I currently have is

```
   SELECT S#, SNAME FROM S WHERE CITY = 'London';
```

but the S# part gives me an operator error. I've tried casting it as a varchar and doing [S#] but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks or double quotes to escape the name:

```
SELECT `S#`, SNAME
FROM S
WHERE CITY = 'London';
```

When you design your own databases, don't use such characters in names.  Stick to letters, numbers, and underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Backticks, Double Quotes, and Single Quotes** in any MySQL database can be summarized into two points:

- Quotes (Single and Double) are used around strings.
- Backticks are used around table and column identifiers.

Using backticks in your query,

```
SELECT `S#`, SNAME
FROM S
WHERE CITY = 'London';
```

These backticks are called quoted identifiers and they tell the parser to handle the text between them as a literal string. They are useful for when you have a column or table that contains a keyword or space or some special character.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the backticks around that column name work but double quotes don't.

Comment: Add more detail to your answer.